# Existance of $w$ such that $\|u_0 - w\| = d(u_o,\mathcal{N}(f))$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $U$ be a normed space, $f\in U'$ where $U'$is the deual space, and $u_o\notin \mathcal{N}(f)$ where $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is the null space.

How to show that there is a vector $w\in \mathcal{N}(f)$ such that $\|u_o - w\| = d(u_o,\mathcal{N}(f))$ if and only if there exists a vector $u \in U$ such that $\|u\| = 1$ and $f(u) = \|f\|$.

I dont know how to start>>>any help??

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $v=u_0-w$. The search for $v$ is the search for a vector of smallest norm such that $f(v)=f(x_0)$. This is directly related to the search for vector $u$ with unit norm such that $f(u)$ is as large as possible.

Indeed, if $v$ exists, then $u=\dfrac{v}{\|v\|}$ solves the second extremal problem.

Conversely,  if $u$ exists, then $v=\dfrac{f(x_0)}{\|f\|}u$ solves the first one.